# Send Raw notification to Windows Phone 8.1 via Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I need to send different data via push notification to my Windows Phone 8.1 application and handle it into background task. How I can send Raw notification via Parse.com? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been struggling for a very long time with Parse.com and Windows Push Notifications.

I haven't been able to send Raw notifications to Windows Phone so far. Neither I am able to send specific parameters as "sound", for example.

Parse.com simply seems to give no support to those kind of Windows Phone notifications. Only "regular" push notifications with a Title.

Comment: Sorrowfully... It is very strange that this feature isn't supported. Is the bad news for me. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @DmitryButrimov and now they announce they are going to "die". Nice move.